# How to disable a chosen drop down list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm desperatly trying to disable a chosen drop down list through jQuery (1.11.3).
The following code lines are all my attempts to get it work:

```
$("#jform_catid_chzn").prop('disabled', true).trigger('listz:updated');
$("#jform_catid_chzn").prop('disabled', 'disabled').trigger('listz:updated');
$("#jform_catid_chzn").attr('disabled', true).trigger('listz:updated');
$("#jform_catid_chzn").attr('disabled', 'disabled').trigger('listz:updated');
$("#jform_catid_chzn").prop('disabled', true).trigger('chosen:updated');
$("#jform_catid_chzn").prop('disabled', 'disabled').trigger('chosen:updated');
$("#jform_catid_chzn").attr('disabled', true).trigger('chosen:updated');
$("#jform_catid_chzn").attr('disabled', 'disabled').trigger('chosen:updated');
```

Unfortunately none of them has succeeded so far.
Of course I've checked the triggered id  and it is correct.

Can someone please help me on this one ?

Comment: Show us your HTML too, please

Comment: For what purpose you are using trigger?

Comment: With just disabling it there is no problem. The trigger is causing the mess `$("#dropdown").prop("disabled", true);` [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y8toez60/1/)

Comment: Here's the HTML code:

`<div class="chzn-container chzn-container-single chzn-container-single-nosearch" style="width: 220px;" title="" id="jform_catid_chzn">
<a class="chzn-single" tabindex="-1">
<span>- Odyssey</span>
<div><b></b></div></a>
<div class="chzn-drop"><div class="chzn-search"><input type="text" autocomplete="off" readonly=""></div>
<ul class="chzn-results">
<li class="active-result result-selected" style="" data-option-array-index="0">- Odyssey</li>
<li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="1">- Step Sequences</li>
</ul></div></div>`

Comment: `$("#dropdown").prop("disabled", true);` doesn't work neither.

Answer (score 1):

Just stumbled accross this question as I had the same problem and it is still not solved..

```
$("#jform_catid_chzn").attr('disabled', true).trigger('listz:updated');
```

it should be:

```
$("#jform_catid").attr('disabled', true).trigger('liszt:updated');
```

1. when you are using plugin commands you are targeting your original
   dropdown (without "_chzn")
2. "listz" should now be "liszt"

Answer (score 0):

Using `JavaScript`

```html
<script>
function disable() {
    document.getElementById("mySelect").disabled=true;
}
function enable() {
    document.getElementById("mySelect").disabled=false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>


<select id="mySelect">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Pear</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input type="button" onclick="disable()" value="Disable list">
<input type="button" onclick="enable()" value="Enable list">
```

using `jquery`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#chkdwn2").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $("#dropdown").prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
      $("#dropdown").prop("disabled", false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown" style="width:200px;">
  <option value="feedback" name="aft_qst">After Quest</option>
  <option value="feedback" name="aft_exm">After Exam</option>
</select>

<input type="checkbox" id="chkdwn2" value="feedback" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but the pb comes specifically from the chosen plugin, if I deactivate it my code works fine.